# prevent toggleClass when click on specific div area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this [**dropdown menu**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mareksmakosz/8aKgY/2/).
So far, when I click on "Menu", submenu drops down and when I click again on "Menu" or the sub-links, it collapses again.

What I need, is to prevent this behavior, and `toggleClass('clicked')` only when I click the "Menu".
The markup should stay as it is.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** here to prevent click event of main menu getting triggered and collapse your menu when clicking on the sub menu:

```
$('.productSubmenu').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8aKgY/4/)**

Comment: sometimes e.stopPropagation(); can't work, add return false will be better

Comment: @TechStone could you specify "sometimes"?

Comment: stopPropagation is prevent event distribution, preventDefault is prevent event's action